# Which directive to use in angularJS to bind properties in inner html by using property directly

Tags: angularjs

Following code works when I use `val.name, val.age.`

```
<body ng-app=''>
    <div ng-init='val = {name:"shan", age:32}'></div>
    <div ng-model='val'>{{name}} - {{age}}</div>
```

### [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pt04us6w/)

What I want is not to use `val.` everytime. I should be able to bind all the properties within nested html elements. i.e. since val is binding to parent div all inner html controls should get binded to `parent.` automatically.

**Edit:**

My val variable contains 1000 properties and I binded all of them in my html form. What if some day my val property got changed to value. Why not simply use val on parent html element and bind remaining fields with property name available with val property.

I want this

```
<div val>
 {{property1}}
 {{property2}}
 {{property3}}


 {{property1000}}
</div>
```

instead of

```
<div val>
 {{val.property1}}
 {{val.property2}}
 {{val.property3}}


 {{val.property1000}}
</div>
```

Comment: Please add comments for -ve points.

Comment: "Should" is not the way the framework was built to work. Variables exist given the controller scope, not based on elements.

Comment: I have seen this before while learning tutorial at codeschool but I am completely blank how did they use. So I am sure what I am trying to achieve is 100% possible. Its just I may be using wrong terminology

Comment: First: you can't apply ng-model to div elements: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/docs/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: I don't know which directive to use what I am trying to achieve. Idea is I want to use `{{name}}` in inner html rather than `{{val.name}}`. What if I have 100 fields to bind and my property changes in future

Comment: What Fals said and what is your problem with the dot notation that is the way javascript works entering a method or property. You have to repeat it? Use ng-repeat.

Comment: This example is possible: http://jsfiddle.net/fals/m9711onq/1/ each repeat line will be bound to the refer array item, if you change one of those this will reflect the repeat.

Comment: Please see my edit. I am not using an array. my val variable is a json object with 1000 properties

Comment: @ShantanuGupta Well, I don't know any other way to access a JSON object property without  the object name + property name, ex: obj.property or obj['property']. When you access the propertime {{name}} mens that the variable is directly nested inside the $scope, ex: $scope.name = 'my name'

Comment: If you want to use {{ property1 }}, then the scope must have a field named property1. I can't imagine how you can have 1000 properties in a single page, and I find your idea terrible, but you could simply use `angular.extend($scope, val)` to copy all the properties of val to the scope.

Comment: I am watching all video of codeschool again to find out what I am referring to. I don't want to repeat my variable name again and again. I just want to use it at parent html control. Same thing is available in WPF as well.

Comment: 1000 properties is hypothetical. Its just to express a need of not using obj in obj.property1

Comment: @ShantanuGupta the extend from scope can solve your issue as JB Nizet said

Comment: OK, so 1000 is in fact 10. Deal with it, and use person.name instead of name. It makes things much clearer, and if you rename person into people, you just need a query/replace, that shouldn't take more than 1 minute.

Comment: I may be very bad at explaining my thoughts what I am trying to achieve. But my purpose is not to finish the job. I am just learning things by messing up myself into problems.

Comment: @ShantanuGupta this example reflects what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/fals/m9711onq/2/

Comment: @Fals: So sorry I am not able to express what I am looking for. Since I have seen it so I want to find it and use it again. But what you just used is not what I have seen in tutorial before. I will post it as an answer to what I am searching if I could find it.

Comment: @ShantanuGupta Maybe you are confusing with something else?

Comment: Absolutely possible and may be I am messing up everyone. That's why going back to tutorial.

Comment: @ShantanuGupta this exemple looks more with you question: http://jsfiddle.net/fals/m9711onq/3/